# How do you set Entry parameter 'show' in Tkinter to always show fixed number of asterisks in Entry field?

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords, tkinter-entry

I set the 'show' parameter to '*' so that Entry field doesn't reveal what was typed in. The issue I am having is, it hints how long the word actually is. So, for example, if I type in word 'blue', it will show as '****' which hints it's a 4 characters long word. Also, the solution code needs to work with the random function filling in the above mentioned field

How do I solve this easy way?

EDIT: To put things into a context this is the code of the app I made.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

def num_guess():
    try:
        int(num_input.get())

    except ValueError:
        Ans = "You must enter a number in your number field!\n"
        result_field.insert(INSERT, Ans)

    if int(num_input.get()) == int(hidden_num):
        Ans = "Congrats you guessed correctly!\n"
        result_field.insert(INSERT, Ans)
        secret_num.delete(0, END)
        secret_num.insert(END, hidden_num) 

    elif int(num_input.get()) in range(int(hidden_num) - 2, int(hidden_num) + 3):
        Ans = "You are very close to secret number!..." + str(num_input.get()) + "\n"    
        result_field.insert(INSERT, Ans)

    elif int(num_input.get()) in range(int(hidden_num) - 5, int(hidden_num) + 6):
        Ans = "You are close to secret number!..." + str(num_input.get()) + "\n"    
        result_field.insert(INSERT, Ans)

    elif int(num_input.get()) in range(int(hidden_num) - 10, int(hidden_num) + 11):
        Ans = "You are relatively close to secret number!..." + str(num_input.get()) + "\n"    
        result_field.insert(INSERT, Ans)

    elif int(num_input.get()) in range(int(hidden_num) - 15, int(hidden_num) + 16):
        Ans = "You are far from secret number!..." + str(num_input.get()) + "\n"   
        result_field.insert(INSERT, Ans)

    else:
        Ans = "You are very far from secret number!..." + str(num_input.get()) + "\n"   
        result_field.insert(INSERT, Ans)

def start_new():
    global hidden_num
    result_field.delete('1.0', END)
    secret_num.delete(0, END)
    secret_num.insert(END, random.randint(1,100)) 
    hidden_num = secret_num.get()
    secret_num.delete(0, END)
    secret_num.insert(END, "***")
    result_field.insert(INSERT, "Now enter your number as a guess!\n") 

def hide_num():
    global hidden_num

    try:
        int(secret_num.get())
        hidden_num = secret_num.get()
        secret_num.delete(0, END)
        secret_num.insert(END, "***")
        result_field.insert(INSERT, "Now enter your number as a guess!\n") 

    except ValueError:
        Ans = "You must enter a number in secret number field!\n"
        result_field.insert(INSERT, Ans)    

hidden_num = 0

window = Tk()
window.title('Guess the Number!')
Label(window, text = "").grid(row=0)
Label(window, text = "Secret number:").grid(row=7, column=1, padx=8)
Label(window, text = "Enter your number:").grid(row=8, column=1, padx=8)
Label(window, text = "").grid(row=10)

#find textbox code!
result_field = Text(window, width=54, height=18)
result_field.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=6, rowspan=6, padx=8)
result_field.insert(INSERT, "Click 'Start new' to start a new game!\n") 

sb1 = Scrollbar(window)
sb1.grid(row=1, column=7, rowspan=6, sticky = 'NS')
result_field.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command = result_field.yview)

secret_num = Entry(window, width=6)
secret_num.grid(row=7, column=2)

num_input = Entry(window, width=6)
num_input.grid(row=8, column=2)                                                                         

b1 = Button(window, text = "Take a guess!", command=num_guess, width=12)
b1.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=8, padx=8)
b2 = Button(window, text = "Start new", command=start_new, width=12)
b2.grid(row=9, column=2, pady=8, padx=8)
b3 = Button(window, text = "Quit", command=window.destroy, width=12)
b3.grid(row=9, column=3, pady=8, padx=8) 
b4 = Button(window, text = "Hide number", command=hide_num, width=12)
b4.grid(row=7, column=3, sticky = 'W')

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you set Entry parameter 'show' in Tkinter to always show fixed number of asterisks in Entry field? .. How do I solve this easy way?

There is no easy way, and there's no way to use the `show` attribute to hide the length other than to set show to whitespace.

If you need something more secure you'll have to create your own bindings that accept input from a user and then display something else.

Comment: I added a variable which stores the value from the field then replaces value with 3 asterisks. If there is an easier solution I am open to suggestions.  I edited my post so you can check the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

passwordInput = Entry(root, show = "   ‍   ")
passwordInput.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Make sure to copy the code in the `show =` carefully. It will be not the same length as an empty space so to throw people off. Copy it here (between the quotes): "   ‍   "
Note that it is an [iEmpty](https://iempty.tooliphone.net/en/create-ios-folder-without-name-no-text/) blank character

If you want, you can set the show to this:  (just a space key)